# Magento 2 - Slick slider function not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, ajax, slick

`Slick slider` function is not working after `ajax` response, This is the order of my code. Firstly I got a product collection response, Then I wrote a slick slider function. but slider function is not working.

This is dom element in phtml file in which ajax response appear

```
<div class="category-products clearfix products wrapper grid products-grid">
    <ol class="products list items product-items featured-collector featured-collector_<?php echo $categoryid; ?>">
    </ol>
</div>
```

This is my js code

```
require([
    'jquery'
    ], function($){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/manufacturerpages/index/collection",
        type: "POST",
        data: "id= <?php echo $manpagedataarr['page_id']; ?>&categoryid=<?php echo $categoryid; ?>&carouselorder=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['carouselorder']; ?>&collection_type=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['collection_type']; ?>&product_ids=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['product_ids']; ?>&manufacturer=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['manufacturer']; ?>",
        success: function (res) {
            //console.log(res);
            var result = jQuery('.product-items', res).html();
            var undefined = false;
            if(typeof result === 'undefined'){
                result = res;
                undefined = true;
            }

            jQuery(".featured-collector_<?php echo $categoryid; ?>").html(result);
            jQuery(".landing-featured .ajax_loading").hide();
            jQuery( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();
        }

    });
});

require([
    'jquery',
    'magiccart/slick',
        'alothemes'
    ], function($, slick){
    jQuery('.featured-collector_<?php echo $categoryid; ?>').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: false,
        draggable: true,
        speed: 300
    });
});
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: There is no any error in my console.

Comment: where you are writing js code? in phtml or separate js file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually one of possible reason why it may not properly working because you don't add the `slick` after ajax success response. You just need to replace this, with your js code

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'magiccart/slick',
    'alothemes'
    ], function($, slick){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/manufacturerpages/index/collection",
        type: "POST",
        data: "id= <?php echo $manpagedataarr['page_id']; ?>&categoryid=<?php echo $categoryid; ?>&carouselorder=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['carouselorder']; ?>&collection_type=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['collection_type']; ?>&product_ids=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['product_ids']; ?>&manufacturer=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['manufacturer']; ?>",
        success: function (res) {
            //console.log(res);
            var result = jQuery('.product-items', res).html();
            var undefined = false;
            if(typeof result === 'undefined'){
                result = res;
                undefined = true;
            }

            jQuery(".featured-collector_<?php echo $categoryid; ?>").html(result);
            jQuery(".landing-featured .ajax_loading").hide();

            // ******This is your slick code***********
             jQuery('.featured-collector_<?php echo $categoryid; ?>').slick({
                    dots: false,
                    infinite: true,
                    slidesToShow: 6,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    arrows: true,
                    autoplay: false,
                    draggable: true,
                    speed: 300
            });
            jQuery( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();
        }

    });
});
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: let me try this, come back to you

Comment: Don't think it is as easy :)

Comment: @MuhammadAnas  Adding to the answer, Might be take as future reference, In **javascript code is execute sequentially, or line by line** so in after **Ajax call, request sent to the server but it not guarantee that result will come before next line of code execute**, so better to wait for dependent code (in your case slick), so need to **add code in success callback function which will execute after response came from server**.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely your AJAX request is completing AFTER the slider is initialised, see if adding your Slick JS to your success callback helps:

```
require([
    'jquery'
    ], function($){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/manufacturerpages/index/collection",
        type: "POST",
        data: "id= <?php echo $manpagedataarr['page_id']; ?>&categoryid=<?php echo $categoryid; ?>&carouselorder=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['carouselorder']; ?>&collection_type=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['collection_type']; ?>&product_ids=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['product_ids']; ?>&manufacturer=<?php echo $manpagedataarr['manufacturer']; ?>",
        success: function (res) {
            //console.log(res);
            var result = jQuery('.product-items', res).html();
            var undefined = false;
            if(typeof result === 'undefined'){
                result = res;
                undefined = true;
            }

            jQuery(".featured-collector_<?php echo $categoryid; ?>").html(result);
            jQuery(".landing-featured .ajax_loading").hide();
            jQuery( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();

jQuery('.featured-collector_<?php echo $categoryid; ?>').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: false,
        draggable: true,
        speed: 300
    });
        }
    });
});
```

If so I recommend you split your JS up into Require JS modules rather than inlining it inside a template then you can keep them separate and still call it in your success callback. I see JS inside PHTML as a bad practice, it makes maintenance much harder and I think it prevents your JS from being cached.

Comment: your answer is also correct but I can mark anyone answer correct. Still +1 for your effort. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome :D